How to open azure content safety studio?
I am trying to follow that learning:
https://microsoftlearning.github.io/mslearn-ai-fundamentals/Instructions/Labs/02-content-safety.html
and in there is:
"Open the Content Safety Studio. If you are not logged in, you will need to sign in. Select Sign In on the top right of the screen. Use the email and password associated with your Azure subscription to sign in."
when I try to open there is dark page and I can not see anything
problematic link:
https://contentsafety.cognitive.azure.com/?azure-portal=true
the same problem I found in here, but not saw a solution:https://github.com/MicrosoftLearning/mslearn-ai-fundamentals/issues/13

solution for me was NOT TO USE EDGE, when I used that link in google chrome it is working.
How microsoft's pages are not working in microsoft browsware?

Did you try clearing caches etc. in Edge?

I did tried to open it in incognito

did you tried on your Edge and it worked?

I don't have an account but yeah, that link opened ok in Edge. Have you tried disabling any extensions you have installed? Have had this in the past where an extension has completely broken a site I was visiting.

oh, my bad, you are right, not a browser but extension broke my page, it hapened first time in my life, thanks, I will keep that in mind :D
